With SHA-1 broken, can the old Linux /dev/(u)random algorithm be trusted?
The Linux kernel /dev/(u)random and getrandom(2) system call all use the same CSPRNG, which was originally based on MD5, then SHA-1, and now ChaCha20 since Linux 4.8.
If I use an older version of the Linux kernel than 4.8, I'm still using the SHA-1 variant of CSPRNG.
With SHA-1 broken (we can find collisions), can it be trusted as a CSPRNG?


With SHA-1 broken (we can find collisions), can it be trusted as a CSPRNG?

Yes. There is still no (public) attack that distinguish the output of SHA-1 from random better than guessing the input.
This is not to be construed as an endorsement of any particular /dev/(u)random, which could be broken for reasons independent of SHA-1.
Independently: we should no longer use SHA-1 for new designs.

Yes it can. The SHA-1 implementation in /dev/urandom worked around SHA1 issues by using multiple rounds and truncated outputs (it never gave you the full inner state of the sha1, and the output was of more than 1 rounds of sha1)
BTW 5.17 switched to Blake2s - as mentioned in the article, this significantly increased the speed of /dev/urandom , not because blake2s is significantly faster than sha1 (it's actually slightly slower), but because they could (and did) drop fugly hacks to make sha1 secure, and the security-hacks had a significant performance impact.

Oh, there seems to be two layers in the random device. Firstly, SHA1 or Blake2s collecting entropy, then MD5 or SHA1 or ChaCha20 converting that entropy to random device output.
